# Бот не подключается к телеграмм на Python

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot

Изучаю как написать на питоне бот на телеграмм и столкнулась с проблемой, что не подключается к боту программа из-за блокировки. Нашла инфу, что нужно прокси подключить. Вот только не пойму как его подключить к функции передачи.

```
from telebot import apihelper
import telebot

token = 'xxxx'

apihelper.proxy = {'http':'http://10.10.1.10:3128'
                   }

bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет, ты написал мне /start')

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_text(message):
    if message.text.lower() == 'привет':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет, мой создатель')
    elif message.text.lower() == 'пока':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Прощай, создатель')

bot.polling()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
apihelper.proxy = {'https': 'socks5h://geek:socks@t.geekclass.ru:7777'}
```

Это 99% рабочий прокси, у меня он работает. Попробуйте его.

Answer (score 0):

Из [Документации](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI#proxy)

```
apihelper.proxy = {'https':'socks5://userproxy:password@proxy_address:port'}
```

Comment: я видела это - там 2 вариант. по http и по htpps. тут я вижу userproxy:password@proxy_address:port  пароль и порт - где их взять?

Comment: нашла такой вариант apihelper.proxy = {'http':'http://10.10.1.10:3128'} как его подключить к функции отправки сообщения?

Comment: @Каролина Если Вы пользуетесь бесплатным `proxy`, то в большинстве случаев, логин с паролём Вам не понадобятся. Поэтому код, который Вы привели выше, уже делает то, что Вам нужно (при условии работоспособности `proxy`).

Comment: Благодарю за помощь